# Way to save vectors in a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, permutation

I have a problem with the TSP algorithm
. I'm going to insert code and explain:

```
List listOfPermutations = new ArrayList();
while (cont.compareTo(deleteRutes) < 0) { 
    listOfPermutations.add(indexOfCities);
    nextPermutation(indexOfCities);
    ....
```

The problem I have is the following, 
my idea was to insert all possible permutations (arrays) in a list, but the problem is that the list always takes the same values ​​of the array, it is logical since the indexOfCities array is only one. I've been giving it back for a while and I do not know how to solve it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to create copies of `indexOfCities` and add those to `listOfPermutations`

Comment: @MichaelButscher but how do I know how many copies I have to create?

Comment: Each time you want to add to `listOfPermutations` you need a copy because (I guess) `nextPermutation` will then modify `listOfPermutations` in place.

Comment: @MichaelButscher `nextPermutation` is in charge of making the permutations of the city routes of the `indexOfCities` array

Comment: It modifies the array `indexOfCities` (that was meant with "in place") but you need unmodified copies in `listOfPermutations`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher but how do I declare many copies for all the permutations, because if we declare a single copy we would have the same problem, right?

Comment: You only have to declare one additional variable (in fact, not only this, but it would be less clear), assign the copy to this variable and use the variable in the `add` call. In the next iteration a new copy can be assigned to the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOfCities` holds a reference to an array. This same reference is added as item to `listOfPermutations` with

```
listOfPermutations.add(indexOfCities);
```

in each loop iteration.

Then the array is modified with

```
nextPermutation(indexOfCities);
```

in each loop iteration. So the stored references all point to the same modified array.

To solve this, add a copy of the array in `indexOfCities` to `listOfPermutations` instead. E.g. like so:

```
int[] indexOfCitiesAux = indexOfCities.clone();
listOfPermutations.add(indexOfCitiesAux);
```